# Nodejs is not receiving any code from Flask app.

Tags: node.js, http, flask, request

I am really new in node js and a little bit more experienced in flaks. I am trying to connect a nodejs backend with a flask api. Basically I am sending a file that was uploaded in the nodejs app for processing (converting to another format) to my flask app.

For sending the data I am using request. In this way:

```
app.post('/converttest', uploader.single('file'), function(req,res){
var file = req.file,
        result = {
        error: 0,
        uploaded: []
    };

flow.exec(
    function() { // Read temp File
        fs.readFile(file.path, this);
    },
    function(err, data) { // Upload file to S3
        var formData = {
            file: data,
        };
        requestPack.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource/converter', formData: formData});
    },
    function(err, httpResponse, body) { //Upload Callback
        if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
        res.redirect('/console');
    });
});
```

Then I am receiving the file for processing in the flask app, like:

```
@app.route('/api/resource/converter', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def converter_csv():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.form['file']
    if not f:
        abort(400)

    print('-----Converting-------')
    file = open("temp/converting.txt","w")
    file.write(f)
    #....conversion process... 
    # Finish the process 

    return Response(converted_file,status=200)
```

In my console for the localhost of the flask app, I am getting:

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2017 15:47:59] "POST /api/resource/converter HTTP/1.1" 200 -

However my nodejs app did not receive any response. It just got frozen.

I appreciate any orientation anyone can give me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I think flow.exec is not in proper order**

```
router.post('/converttest', uploader.single('file'), function(req, res) {
var filePath = req.file.path;
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) { //change format reading as required
    try {
       formData = {file:data}
       requestPack.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource/converter', formData: formData});
    } catch(err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        res.redirect('/console')
    }
    fs.unlink(filePath);}); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested using your Idea but I got. this in the terminal  (node:74809) DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. Seems it wasn't processed either

Comment: You were right, the structure of my nodejs app was what I got wrong. I post the solution I used. But thanks for pointing me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using requestify. Seems like they make it a little bit easier for beginners like me:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');
app.get('/convertupload', function(req,res){
res.render('pages/convertupload');
});
app.post('/converttest', uploader.single('file'), function(req,res){
var file = req.file,
        result = {
        error: 0,
        uploaded: []
    };

flow.exec(
    function() { // Read temp File
        fs.readFile(file.path,this);
    },
    function(err, data) { // Upload file to S3
        var formData = {
            file: data
        };


    requestify.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource/converter', {
             form: formData
            })
        .then(function(response) {
        // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
        console.log(response)
        response.getBody();
        });

        res.redirect('/login');
    });
});
```

Comment: Requestify is straightforward!